# Oracle filtering with multiple Exists but only one can evaluate

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, where-clause, exists

Please consider this pseudo-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE 
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.ID = :ID)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM C WHERE C.NAME = :NAME)
```

Consider that:

- "From A" is much more complex and I don't want to do more joins there.
- I'm filtering results and foreach record A i just want to return a single row, that's why I have the exists in the order i want them to evaluate;

How can I avoid running the 2nd exists (due to performance) if the first one already evaluates "true"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE 
    1 = CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.ID = :ID) THEN 1
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM C WHERE C.NAME = :NAME) THEN 1
    END
```

This takes advantage of the *short-circuit evaluation* behavior of `case`, which is [described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96):

> For a searched `CASE` expression, the database evaluates each condition to determine whether it is true, and never evaluates a condition if the previous condition was true.

Comment: Thanks, this is a cleaver solution.

Comment: What if both are true

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: the `case` evaluation stops on the first condition that succeeds. So if the first condition is met, the second one is not even evaluated.

Comment: Well i din mean that though i thought that both the conditions getting true would give 2 1s at the same time hence a subquery required to compensate or am aggregate but i still doubt your answer

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: *both the conditions getting true would give 2 1s at the same time*: no; a `case` expression returns a single value.